# What is the correct HTTP redirect status code?

Tags: http, redirect

I have implemented friendly URL's on my site and I can access products and categories in two ways via the URL.

1. http://www.example.com/home/electronics/tablets
2. http://www.example.com/tablets

Now when URL http://www.example.com/tablets is navigated to, it does a permanent redirect (301) to http://www.example.com/home/electronics/tablets but is this the correct redirect code?

I was thinking maybe it should be a 303?  Any suggestions would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

301 is correct. You are always going to be redirecting there.

302 is inappropriate, you want the result to be cached.

303, to quote the specification, "exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to redirect the user agent to a selected resource. The new URI is not a substitute reference for the originally requested resource." So that isn't suitable either.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. 301 is what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether it's a permanent (301) or a temporary (302) redirection. In practice, it doesn't make a significant difference in browsers.

Why do you think that *303* is suitable?

Comment: I think I just got confused with the redirect codes. I always want to do a permanent redirect, which is 301.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302). It's pretty standard.

Edit: 301 is definitely correct as it's a permanent redirect. I misread the question.

Comment: It is completely standard … but isn't suitable for this purpose.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the question!