# How to do a server side HTTP redirection instead of a meta refresh

Tags: java, http, redirect

According to W3 Meta refresh is discouraged and they recommend Server side redirection. So my question is how am I supposed to do that in HTTPServer?

The API does not provide any redirection method here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html

If this "redirection" is not that abstract thing, then what would be the idea behind that?

Comment: You mean this: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback ?

Comment: @Raedwald Yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

What the W3 means when is says [this](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback), is that instead of your HTTP server returning a status-code of 200 (OK) with a response body that has HTML with a

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; URL=http://www.example.org/bar">
```

you have your HTTP server return a suitable [3xx (redirect)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) status code, with a `Location` header that gives the location to be redirected to.

The [most suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289812/what-is-the-correct-http-redirect-status-code) status code would be [302 (Found)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) if you still expect people to use the original URL as an alias for the URL being redirected too (the HTTP standard says "the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests").

If you want users to stop using the original URL the most suitable status code would be [301 (Moved Permanently)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2).

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that? As in can you give an example of Location header to be sent?

Comment: @SarpKaya Read the the documentation for `HttpServer`, `HttpHandler` and `HttpExchange`. Ask a new question if you have a specific difficulty about them. This website is not a code writing service.

Comment: I am sorry, I am trying to do:

"     exchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Location", "/redirect");
     exchange.sendResponseHeaders(301, -1);"

But it just opens a blank page. That's why I asked an example.

Comment: @SarpKaya Thanks a lot! I changed my #sendResponseHeaders(302, 1) to (302, -1) and now it works.